# How do I get the "children" or contents of a function?

Tags: javascript

For example, if my script is...

```
function cool() {
    function yes() { alert('yes'); }
    function wow() { alert('wow'); }
}
```

And I use `cool.toString();` then I get the entire function as a string.

But what do I have to do to just get the inner-contents as a string:

```
    function yes() { alert('yes'); }
    function wow() { alert('wow'); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `toString` to get the entire function, like just did in your example
2. Replace the beginning of the toStringed-function, all the way until (and including) the first `{` with an empty string.
3. Remove the last character of the toStringed-function.

Like this:

```
cool.toString().replace(/^[^{]*{/, "").slice(0, -1)
```